# Ring with every element idempotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, boolean-ring

I am having query in this MCQ.
Let $R$ be  a ring such that every element is idempotent then

(a) Every prime ideal is maximal ideal.

(b) Every maximal ideal is prime ideal

(c) if $|R|> 2$ implies $R$ never ID

(d) If $|R| > 2$ implies $R$ never field.

As every element is idempotent, they are taking about Boolean ring. And in Boolean ring every prime ideal is maximal and every maximal is prime hence option a and b is true. How to deal with option c and d. Actually both c and d are also given true. Can u explain or hint me why both has to be true. Just hint me, why for $|R|> 2$ is not Integral domain.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Assuming "ring" means "ring with (multiplicative) identity": if it was ID, then for every $x$ you have $x^2=x$ i.e. $x(x-1)=0$, so either $x=0$ or $x=1$. Thus the ring has at most two elements.

Comment: What is an MCQ?

Comment: Multiple Choice Question

Comment: To add to Stinking bishop's comment(sounds weird huh....) . A field is always an integral domain.